# How to pass const string into function

Tags: c#, switch-statement, constants

How do I pass a const string into a method to be used in a switch statement?

#### Context

I currently have a program that will parse a file based on customized markers. The markers are constant for the purposes of the program, but ideally can be changed between instances of running the program.  I currently have the markers hard coded. I then use them in several switch statements. That works great. However, while refactoring my code, I have been unable to replicate the behavior, because I can't pass the const string variables into the function. While I could just hard code the declaration in the method, that is not ideal nor practical for obvious reasons.

#### I have Tried

1. passing the variables as a ref to the original const variables:
   `Method(ref string keyIndicator)`
2. passing the variables with the 'in' keyword :
   `Method(in string keyIndicator)`
3. redeclaring the variables constant based on both of the above:
   `Method(ref string keyIndicator)` and `Method(in string keyIndicator)` followed by :
   `const string kIndicator = keyIndicator;`

#### Tangent

No matter what I do, I get an error:

> The expression being assigned to 'x' must be constant.

But it is constant.
As a side question, why is it that I can not logically assign a constant to a variable (hear me out), such that on initialization, the const string is set for the life of the program?  For example:

On program run, program asks user for their name, and then that value is stored in a constant variable.

`const string hi = Console.ReadLine();` <- gives me an error.

#### TLDR

I need to use variables for my switch statement, which I am already doing by hardcoding a constant variable. However, I am trying to refactor my code, and move these switch statements into methods, which as best I can tell, will not allow me to pass the constant variable. I know I must be missing something, as surely do not hardcode all their switch selections, and surely they use switches in methods. So, help a floundering beginner out?

Due to Requests for Code...

Original Code (roughly, I had to jigger it a bit to emulate what it would look like in the context of my program). I'm more confused than ever, because while trying to trim down the code to place here, it actually DID work. But only in a secondary file. I copied the code back to my program, and it doesn't. >:/.

WORKING test file Created to show what I was trying to do...

```
    internal class Program{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string fileToParse = "!--------------------Demo Key@--------------------DemoBody#--------------------DemoClinical";
        //
        //
        //!!!!!Set Constants for Deliniators!!!!
        //
        //
        const string divider = "--------------------";
        const string keySign = "!";
        const string bodySign = "@";
        const string clinicalSign = "#";
        //
        //
        //!!!!!Set Constants for Deliniators!!!!
        //
        //
        const string keyIndicator = keySign + divider;
        const string bodyIndicator = bodySign + divider;
        const string clinicalIndicator = clinicalSign + divider;
        //
        //
        List<String> checkDeliniators = new List<String>();
        checkDeliniators.Add(keyIndicator);
        checkDeliniators.Add(bodyIndicator);
        checkDeliniators.Add(clinicalIndicator);

        SetIndexes(ref fileToParse, checkDeliniators);


        static void SetIndexes(ref string fileToParse, List<string> checkDeliniators)
        {

            //Create Lists of indexes (Starts and Stops for Text desired)
            foreach (var indicator in checkDeliniators)
            {
                int index = 0;
                while ((fileToParse.IndexOf(indicator, index)) != -1)
                {
                    index = fileToParse.IndexOf(indicator, index);      //  (Undesired text"!"------Desired text)
                    index = index + indicator.Length;                   //  (Undesired text!-------""Desired text)  

                    //assigns this index to the appropriate list
                    switch (indicator)
                    {
                        case keyIndicator:
                            Console.WriteLine("Key start {0}", index);
                            break;
                        case bodyIndicator:
                            Console.WriteLine("body start {0}", index);
                            break;
                        case clinicalIndicator:
                            Console.WriteLine("clinical start {0}", index);
                            break;
                        default:
                            // Do this;
                            break;
                    }

                    //sets END of Text 
                    if ((fileToParse.IndexOf(divider, index)) != -1) //(if there are more instances of divider, move index forward)
                    {
                        //indexed moved forward to next divider, and then backed up to desired text END.
                        index = fileToParse.IndexOf(divider, index);    //  (!"-"------) (diver used because next Indicator not predictable)
                        index = index - keySign.Length;                 //  ("!"-------) (Recall end index is not inclusive)

                        switch (indicator)  //refers to prior indicator (end), not next indicator (start)
                        {
                            case keyIndicator:
                                Console.WriteLine("Key end {0}", index);
                                break;
                            case bodyIndicator:
                                Console.WriteLine("body end {0}", index);
                                break;
                            case clinicalIndicator:
                                Console.WriteLine("clinical end {0}", index);
                                break;
                            default:
                                // Do this;
                                break;
                        }
                        index++; // (!"-"-------)  Technically shouldn't be necessary, but just incase search for divider in future...
                    }
                    else //else, if there are no more instances of divider, leave the index alone, and set the end of text to end of file
                    {
                        index = fileToParse.Length;
                        switch (indicator)
                        {
                            case keyIndicator:
                                Console.WriteLine("Key end {0}", index);
                                break;
                            case bodyIndicator:
                                Console.WriteLine("body end {0}", index);
                                break;
                            case clinicalIndicator:
                                Console.WriteLine("clinical end {0}", index);
                                break;
                            default:
                                // Do that;
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Runs with output

```
Key start 21
Key end 29
body start 50
body end 58
clinical start 79
clinical end 91
```

While this same code :

```
    //
    //
    //!!!!!Set Constants for Deliniators!!!!
    //
    //
    const string divider = "--------------------";
    const string keySign = "!";
    const string bodySign = "@";
    const string clinicalSign = "#";
    //
    //
    //!!!!!Set Constants for Deliniators!!!!
    //
    //
    const string keyIndicator = keySign + divider;
    const string bodyIndicator = bodySign + divider;
    const string clinicalIndicator = clinicalSign + divider;
    //
    //
    List<String> checkDeliniators = new List<String>();
    checkDeliniators.Add(keyIndicator);
    checkDeliniators.Add(bodyIndicator);
    checkDeliniators.Add(clinicalIndicator);


    List<String> KeyList = new List<String>();
    List<String> BodyList = new List<String>();
    List<String> ClinicalList = new List<String>();
    List<String> GarbageList = new List<String>();

    List<int> keyStartIndex = new List<int>();
    List<int> bodyStartIndex = new List<int>();
    List<int> clinicalStartIndex = new List<int>();
    List<int> garbageStartIndex = new List<int>();

    List<int> keyEndIndex = new List<int>();
    List<int> bodyEndIndex = new List<int>();
    List<int> clinicalEndIndex = new List<int>();
    List<int> garbageEndIndex = new List<int>();




    
    const string fileSign = "|";
    //const string commentSign = "~";
    //const string allIndicators = keySign + bodySign + clinicalSign;

    string fileStartIndicator = fileSign + divider;
    string fileEndIndicator = divider + fileSign;



    bool headerSet = SetHeader(ref fileToParse, fileStartIndicator, ref fileHeader);
    bool footerSet = SetFooter(ref fileToParse, fileEndIndicator, ref fileFooter);
    SetIndexes(ref fileToParse, checkDeliniators);

    static void SetIndexes(ref string fileToParse, List<string> checkDeliniators)
    {
        //Create Lists of indexes (Starts and Stops for Text desired)
        foreach (var indicator in checkDeliniators)
        {
            int index = 0;
            while ((fileToParse.IndexOf(indicator, index)) != -1)
            {
                index = fileToParse.IndexOf(indicator, index);      //  (Undesired text"!"------Desired text)
                index = index + indicator.Length;                   //  (Undesired text!-------""Desired text)  

                //assigns this index to the appropriate list
                switch (indicator)
                {
                    case keyIndicator:
                        keyStartIndex.Add(index);
                        break;
                    case bodyIndicator:
                        bodyStartIndex.Add(index);
                        break;
                    case clinicalIndicator:
                        clinicalStartIndex.Add(index);
                        break;
                    default:
                        garbageStartIndex.Add(index);
                        break;
                }

                //sets END of Text 
                if ((fileToParse.IndexOf(divider, index)) != -1) //(if there are more instances of divider, move index forward)
                {
                    //indexed moved forward to next divider, and then backed up to desired text END.
                    index = fileToParse.IndexOf(divider, index);    //  (!"-"------) (diver used because next Indicator not predictable)
                    index = index - keySign.Length;                 //  ("!"-------) (Recall end index is not inclusive)

                    switch (indicator)  //refers to prior indicator (end), not next indicator (start)
                    {
                        case keyIndicator:
                            keyEndIndex.Add(index);
                            break;
                        case bodyIndicator:
                            bodyEndIndex.Add(index);
                            break;
                        case clinicalIndicator:
                            clinicalEndIndex.Add(index);
                            break;
                        default:
                            garbageEndIndex.Add(index);
                            break;
                    }
                    index++; // (!"-"-------)  Technically shouldn't be necessary, but just incase search for divider in future...
                }
                else //else, if there are no more instances of divider, leave the index alone, and set the end of text to end of file
                {
                    index = fileToParse.Length;
                    switch (indicator)
                    {
                        case keyIndicator:
                            keyEndIndex.Add(index);
                            break;
                        case bodyIndicator:
                            bodyEndIndex.Add(index);
                            break;
                        case clinicalIndicator:
                            clinicalEndIndex.Add(index);
                            break;
                        default:
                            garbageEndIndex.Add(index);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Gives me the error that the indicators (i.e. "keyIndicator") need to be constant.

Comment: tldr; write the code, or share the code you wrote.

Comment: `ReadLine` doesn't return a constant. It returns a different value every time.

Comment: 1) I'm having a lot of trouble with the code formating properly on this site (which is why you see tiny little snippets). Sorry about that, but the base question is pretty straightforward...no? (I'll try to get some code......)

Comment: 2) Yes, ReadLine returns a different value every time. But that response will never change. That's like saying that a sentence has difference letters in it all the time, so there are no constant sentences.  If I say, "What is your name?" And the user enters "bob". I should be able to set that as a constant throughout the program if I want. The basic principle of initializing a constant variable, to the current instance of a variable (and it then being locked in place like that) does not seem like it should be problematic or controversal.

Comment: No, the question is not clear without code. Paste the code, select it, click the curly-brace-icon to format as code. Are you asking how to use a variable as a label in a switch statement? That's not possible, simply because the grammar of the C# language does not allow it

Comment: A constant by definition is something that is determined at the time the program is compiled. It cannot be anything that is determined when the program is running. If you have a thing that is a string, but it might be one string or might be a different string, it must be a variable. It varies, so it's a variable.

Comment: Thank you. That is helpful, and at least logical. (Time of compile, not time of initiation). It seems const would be far more useful if it was at the time of initiation. Thus I could say:  const string firstResponse = userResponse;   And that "firstResponse" would forever be locked as what it was in that moment. But, I'm sure there is a lot of nitty gritty under the hood that prevent that. Bottom line, I need to use variable in my switch...which must be constant....thus I am in this position. Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: You seem to think that `const` in C# works like `const` in C++.  It does not.  `readonly` in C# is much closer to C++ `const`.  `const` in C# is like C++ `#define` or `constexpr`.

Comment: For "on initialization, the string is set for the life of the program" use `readonly`.  And no, it cannot be used as a switch case.  But you can use an if-else tree to compare variables against `readonly` values.

Comment: Why can't you use `if()` which doesn't have any restrictions on compile time constants?

Comment: I certainly can use if(), and have considered it. I was just trying to use Switch from a theoretical efficiency perspective. The question was more focused around me clarifying and learning, not finding away around the problem. I can do that, but can envision situations in the future where I would want to use a switch within a method, and would like to be prepared for that :).

Comment: BTW. For anyone following....The reason my code worked in one instance, and not the other, turns out to be because in one my method was within Main() (example), and in the other it was outside of main. (my program). Moving the method into main solved the problem. Now my const (declared in main) is accessible to my method without passing it descretely. Interesting. However, while all is working as intended now, I'm curious to those far more experianced than I. How would you go about this in the future? Just use if/else? Can I change my main/method modifiers to permit passing without nesting?

Comment: The M in MWE stands for "minimal". Reduce your example code to the smallest version possible that still exhibits the problem. It makes it easier to reason about it and explain what it does or doesn't. Dumping hundreds of lines of code just scares people away

Answer (score 0):

Only literals or constants can be used in labels of switch statements. Most languages' grammars are specified in that way. If you need to switch on variables, replace your switch statement with an if-else statement.

```cs
var x = …;
var y = …;
switch (z) {
  case x: doX(); break;
  case y: doY(); break;
  default: doOther(); break;
}
```

becomes

```cs
var x = …;
var y = …;
if (z == x) {
  doX();
} else if (z == y) {
  doY();
} else {
  doOther();
}
```

Comment: Probably the most helpful response, so gets an upvote from me. But to be fair, did not really answer the question. The question being why was I having trouble passing a const into a method. I was using a variable (a constant mind you) to run my switch statement already. (so that the const could be declared at the program start, and not have to dig through code to update the " " later..... But, when I refactored my code, to take my loops/switch out of Main, and put it in a seperate method, it broke. All that changed was it moving out of main(). Putting it back in fixed it. So what gives?

Comment: @SilentKnight I don't know. The question didn't contain any code initially. Your expression x isn't a constant, so you cannot use it as a switch label. If it cannot be made a constant, you cannot use it in a switch statement. "A constant" is only something that is declared with the keyword `const`.

Answer (score 0):

In my above code, There was one that worked, and one that didn't, despite the code being identical.

**

### The solution was that one Method was nested within Main() {}. While the other was outside of it.

**

Moving the code into Main() allowed the const variables declared there to pass into the method, and the code functions as intended.  I am still unsure how to pass const across namespaces or outside of main....but for the time being that was my problem.  So to all those, like myself, who like to use switch statements with non-literal cases....There ya go.

I await the knowledge and further clarification to follow :).